# Target only one of the buttons with CSS

Tags: html, css, button, css-selectors

This is a 2 part question, the first one being how do I change the design on only one of my two buttons? I have two submit buttons in HTML, coding being

```
<center>
  <input type='submit' name=skicka value=BEKR&Auml;FTA&nbsp;DRAG>
  <input type='submit' name=skicka2 value=STARTA&nbsp;OM>
</center>
```

and I want to change the design on them individually in CSS. I've tried with this for the first button (in CSS):

```
input:first-child{
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: Tunga;
    background-color: rgb(051,103,149);
    color: white;
}
```

and it works, but

```
input:second-child{ "other coding stuff"}
```

doesn't work to change the other one. What's the problem?

My second question is, how do I place a small "replay"-icon in the far left of the second button? I've tried with this:

```
background-image: url('replaybutton.png');
background-position: 10px 10px; 
background-repeat: no-repeat;
padding-left: 40px;
```

inside the input field but it just doesn't show up. What's the problem here? I'll happily reply to any possible questions. :)

Comment: there is no `second-child`, you have to use `nth-child(2)`

Comment: You're the best. Thanks a ton! Got any clues with the replay icon?

Comment: I did, in fact I copied the idea for the icon part from w3schools.com, but it still doesn't show. Since I started with css like 2 hours ago I can't tell if it's because of some faulty parameter, misplacing, using the url part wrong etc... But you're right, that one is probably a bit easier to look up. Should've thought about that before posting

Comment: Your button background looks like it should work as long as the image is actually in that directory.

Comment: Huh, that's weird. I'll look deeper into that one. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> input:second-child{ "other coding stuff"}
> ```
>
> doesn't work to change the other one... What's the problem?

[smerny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36229851/css-target-only-one-of-the-buttons#comment60090819_36229851) is spot on. There are no `second-child` pseudo classes in CSS and that is the reason why it doesn't do anything. But you should be careful while using `nth-child(2)` to select the second button. The reason I say this is because the `nth-child(2)` pseudo-class selects the ***second child element under the parent*** and not the ***second button element under the parent***.

Now you'd ask me what is the difference between the two. The answer is that **there is no difference between the two for the HTML provided in the question**. So, as you see in the below snippet, the selector works.

```css
input:first-child {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Tunga;
  background-color: rgb(051, 103, 149);
  color: white;
}
input:nth-child(2) {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Tunga;
  background-color: rgb(051, 103, 149);
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<center>
  <input type='submit' name=skicka value=BEKR&Auml;FTA&nbsp;DRAG>
  <input type='submit' name=skicka2 value=STARTA&nbsp;OM>
</center>
```

However if your HTML is changed to something like one of the two samples in the below snippet (both of which are not unthinkable) then you'd see that the `nth-child(2)` does not work (that is, 2nd button is no longer styled). This is because in both these cases the second child element under the parent is not the second button. In one, it is the `<br>` and in another it is the `<label>` element.

```css
input:first-child {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Tunga;
  background-color: rgb(051, 103, 149);
  color: white;
}
input:nth-child(2) {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Tunga;
  background-color: rgb(051, 103, 149);
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<center>
  <input type='submit' name=skicka value=BEKR&Auml;FTA&nbsp;DRAG>
  <br>
  <input type='submit' name=skicka2 value=STARTA&nbsp;OM>
</center>

<hr>

<center>
  <input type='submit' name=skicka value=BEKR&Auml;FTA&nbsp;DRAG>
  <label>Some label</label>
  <input type='submit' name=skicka2 value=STARTA&nbsp;OM>
</center>
```

In both the above cases, the `last-child` selector would select the second button as in both of them the second button is the last child under its parent. But even that selector would not work for all cases because what if there is another element after the second button?. So that is not fool-proof either.

So then what selector is better? The `nth-of-type` selectors are a better fit (but still not the best, I will come to it in a while) because the select ***nth element of a specific type under the parent*** and aren't affected by the presence of other elements. So, as you can see in the first 3 sets in the below snippet, the selector works fine even though there are other elements in between and after the buttons.

```css
input:first-child {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Tunga;
  background-color: rgb(051, 103, 149);
  color: white;
}
input:nth-of-type(2) {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Tunga;
  background-color: rgb(051, 103, 149);
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<center>
  <input type='submit' name=skicka value=BEKR&Auml;FTA&nbsp;DRAG>
  <br>
  <input type='submit' name=skicka2 value=STARTA&nbsp;OM>
</center>

<hr>

<center>
  <input type='submit' name=skicka value=BEKR&Auml;FTA&nbsp;DRAG>
  <label>Some label</label>
  <input type='submit' name=skicka2 value=STARTA&nbsp;OM>
</center>

<hr>

<center>
  <input type='submit' name=skicka value=BEKR&Auml;FTA&nbsp;DRAG>
  <input type='submit' name=skicka2 value=STARTA&nbsp;OM>
  <div>Some content</div>
</center>

<hr>

<center>
  <input type='submit' name=skicka value=BEKR&Auml;FTA&nbsp;DRAG>
  <input type='checkbox' name=chk /> 
  <input type='submit' name=skicka2 value=STARTA&nbsp;OM>
</center>
```

If it works and selects the second button then why is it not the best? It is not the best because `input` elements can be of multiple types but the element type is same for all of them. So the 2nd `input` may not always be the second button. Refer to the 4th set in the above snippet to see what I mean.

The same set of problems indicated above would be applicable for the `first-child` selector also.

---

So, it is better to avoid the `nth-child`, `nth-of-type` selectors unless you are trying to select a group of elements based on a specific pattern. Always use the attributes whose value is defined (and will not change) to select elements. The attributes could be `id` of the element (or) its `name` (or) class. These selectors will never get affected by a change in the HTML structure (like introduction of extra elements in between or before or after the required element, change in order of the elements etc).

In your case, both the buttons have a unique `name` and so you can use the [`[name='value']` selector](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-3/#attribute-selectors) to safely select each button. If you could add an `id` to both the buttons then using it (like `#id`) would be even more safer. Below is a demo with these selectors.

```css
input[name='skicka'] {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Tunga;
  background-color: rgb(051, 103, 149);
  color: white;
}
input[name='skicka2'] {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Tunga;
  background-color: rgb(051, 103, 149);
  color: red;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px aqua;
  background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/20/10/nature/1');
  background-position: 10px 8px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding-left: 40px;
}
```

```html
<center>
  <input type='submit' name=skicka value=BEKR&Auml;FTA&nbsp;DRAG>
  <br>
  <input type='submit' name=skicka2 value=STARTA&nbsp;OM>
</center>

<hr>

<center>
  <input type='submit' name=skicka value=BEKR&Auml;FTA&nbsp;DRAG>
  <label>Some label</label>
  <input type='submit' name=skicka2 value=STARTA&nbsp;OM>
</center>

<hr>

<center>
  <input type='submit' name=skicka value=BEKR&Auml;FTA&nbsp;DRAG>
  <input type='submit' name=skicka2 value=STARTA&nbsp;OM>
  <div>Some content</div>
</center>

<hr>

<center>
  <input type='submit' name=skicka value=BEKR&Auml;FTA&nbsp;DRAG>
  <input type='checkbox' name=chk />
  <input type='submit' name=skicka2 value=STARTA&nbsp;OM>
</center>
```

---

> My second question is, how do I place a small "replay"-icon in the far left of the second button?

This is most likely some issue with your image location because as you can see in the above snippet, the code works fine.

---

**Note:** This is not an attempt to nitpick or find fault with smerny's comment. I just wanted to show you the best way (in my opinion) to address this problem (especially because you've stated that you have just started with CSS). All information provided in this answer are already present in Stack Overflow but are scattered across multiple topics. Hope you find this answer helpful :)